# How to set cakephp radio-button from mysql?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, radio-button

This cakephp form used to edit a mysql record needs to load the state of a radio button from a mysql database. 
The mysql payment_type is enum('Account', 'Credit').
All of the other non-radio-button form inputs reload from the database and payment_type is correctly displayed on another form using this:

```
<?php echo h($purchaseOrder['PurchaseOrder']['payment_type']); ?>
```

Why doesn't this correctly set the radio-button from payment_type?

```
$options = array('account' => 'Account', 'credit' => 'Credit');
$attributes = array('legend' => false, 'value' => 'payment_type');
echo $this->Form->radio('payment_type', $options, $attributes);
```

Comment: (Following the discussion of the answer here since it's no longer relevant to said answer). If all other inputs are magically autopopulating, try the following: do a `pr($this->data)` in your view to check if the relevant data is passed. If it is, change `$this->Form->radio()` to the corresponding `$this->Form->input('payment_type', array('type'=>'radio', 'options'=>$options)` and see if that does the magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attribute array, you should assign value which you want to keep selected by default .

For example you want account to be selected by default then in value you should assign 'account'. So your final attribute will be:

```
$attributes = array('legend' => false, 'value' => 'account');
```

Comment: What if I don't want anything selected by default? IOW: for the add form the user is required by validation to set one of the selections before saving. The add form works. But the edit form needs to load the saved setting from the database.

Comment: If you do not want default selected radio button then you can remove 'value' attribute which means your $attribute array should be like $attributes = array('legend' => false);

Comment: @jacknad The same solution stands. Don't think of it as *default* value rather than *loaded-from-db* value. You'll have to pass the value loaded from the database to the view and do `$attributes = array('value'=>$valueFromDB)` as @Adiya said